# How can I modify this graph?

Tags: graphviz

I have written this code:

```
digraph G {

    A254 -> A10[style=invis];
    A10 -> A9[style=invis];
    A9 -> A8[style=invis];
    A8 -> A7[style=invis];
    A7 -> A6[style=invis];
    A6 -> A5[style=invis];
    A5 -> A4[style=invis];
    A4 -> A3[style=invis];
    A3 -> A2[style=invis];
    A2 -> A1[style=invis];

    A254 -> A8 [label="t"];

    A8 -> A10 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A9 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A7 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A6 [label="t", style=dotted];


    A8 -> A3 [constraint = false, label="t"];

    A3 -> A5 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A4 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A2 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A1 [label="t", style=dotted];


    A254[style=filled]
    A3[style=filled]
    A8[style=filled]
    {rank=same; A254,A10,A9,A8,A7,A6,A5,A4,A3,A2,A1}
}
```

It produces the following graph:
[image]

Actually I have three questions:

1.How can I make the edge A8 -> A3 neater? It looks very bad.

2.How can I make the edges A254 -> A8 + A8 -> A3 rectangular?

3.How can I make this graph vertical?

**EDIT:**

It is essential that the nodes are lined up and in the same order shown in the graph above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, here it is

1. You can make the edge neater by making a suitable adjustments to the distance between nodes and to the size of the nodes. And the most important thing is to force the A8->A3 edge to be longer by setting the `minlen` attribute of the corrosponding edge.

The following code

```
digraph G {

    nodesep=0.5
    node[fixedsize=true, shape="circle", width=0.5]
    A254 -> A10[style=invis];
    A10 -> A9[style=invis];
    A9 -> A8[style=invis];
    A8 -> A7[style=invis];
    A7 -> A6[style=invis];
    A6 -> A5[style=invis];
    A5 -> A4[style=invis];
    A4 -> A3[style=invis];
    A3 -> A2[style=invis];
    A2 -> A1[style=invis];

    A254 -> A8 [label="t"];

    A8 -> A10 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A9 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A7 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A6 [label="t", style=dotted];


    A8 -> A3 [minlen = 3, constraint = false, label="t"];

    A3 -> A5 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A4 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A2 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A1 [label="t", style=dotted];


    A254[style=filled]
    A3[style=filled]
    A8[style=filled]
    {rank=same; A254,A10,A9,A8,A7,A6,A5,A4,A3,A2,A1}
}
```

generates the following graph:

[image]

2. Edges can not be rectangular.
3. You can make the graph vertical by using the command `rotate=90`

Answer (score 0):

This

[image]

is generated from

```
digraph G {

    A254 -> A10[style=invis];
    A10 -> A9[style=invis];
    A9 -> A8[style=invis];
    A8 -> A7[style=invis];
    A7 -> A6[style=invis];
    A6 -> A5[style=invis];
    A5 -> A4[style=invis];
    A4 -> A3[style=invis];
    A3 -> A2[style=invis];
    A2 -> A1[style=invis];

    A254 -> A8 [label="t"];

    A8 -> A10 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A9 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A7 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A8 -> A6 [label="t", style=dotted];


    A8 -> A3 [label="t"];

    A3 -> A5 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A4 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A2 [label="t", style=dotted];
    A3 -> A1 [label="t", style=dotted];


    A254[style=filled]
    A3[style=filled]
    A8[style=filled]
    {rank=same; A254,A8,A3}
}
```

The best thing to do is read the [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) and experiment with the ideas in there

Comment: For me, it is essential for the nodes to be lined up and in order (like the graph  posted in the question).

Comment: If it is "essential" why did you not mention it!  -1

Comment: Why are you mad!! I though it would be clear from the context of the questions I asked. If you reread the questions carefully you will find that meaning included implicitly. Chill out dude and thanks for the downvote.